# Python csv file tokenizing

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python programming and recently I am trying to read a csv file and then save the data from that csv file to a text file. This is the code I am using

```
csv_file = open('example.csv', 'r')
txt_file = open('example.txt', 'w')

with open(txt_file, 'w') as my_output_file:
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as my_input_file:
        [my_output_file.write(" ".join(row)+'\n') for row in csv.reader(my_input_file)]
    my_output_file.close()
```

I am getting this error

```
File "c:\Users\Desktop\Folder\tokenizing.py", line 41, in <module>
    with open(txt_file, 'w') as my_output_file:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Does anyone knows why is it complaining?

Comment: You need to mention the file name in `open` ex: `with open('example.csv', 'w') as my_output_file:
`

Comment: `csv_file = open('example.csv', 'r')

txt_file = open('example.txt', 'w')

with open('example.txt', 'w') as my_output_file:

    with open('example.csv', 'r') as my_input_file:

        [my_output_file.write(" ".join(row)+'\n') for row in 

csv.reader(my_input_file)]

    my_output_file.close()`

Is that what you mean because I am still getting the same error

Comment: The below ans should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the filenames to the open calls and use a for loop not a list comp and let the with context managers of the file objects take care of closing the files:

```
csv_file = 'example.csv'
txt_file = 'example.txt'

with open(txt_file, 'w') as my_output_file:
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as my_input_file:
        for row in csv.reader(my_input_file):
            my_output_file.write(" ".join(row)+'\n')
```